# Chess tactics #4: Black to play and win

Tags: tactics, problems

After the last problem which was very hard I'm bringing you another one which is easier than the previous one. The position is:

```
[fen "K4R2/RQ4B1/2n5/3q2p1/4PP1p/3p4/pp6/1kr5 w - - 0 1"]
```

White has just played Qg2 and it's going to lose very quickly. **What is the winning move for Black in this position?**

This problem is taken again from the [Chess Tactics Server](http://chess.emrald.net/index.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White threatens mate on g7, but

> 1. ... Ne1 pins the queen (and threatens Rf1#; Qxe4 won't stop that) 2. Rxe1 Qxe1+ 3. Qg1 Rf1 wins the queen

and the remaining endgame is easily won for Black.

Comment: Your move has another purpose, too...

Comment: blocking the Rc1's line to f1.